# Python: What should go in __delete__ method

Tags: python

I am new to Python, I want to understand more the purpose of the `__delete__` method.

In my case I got a class that opens a file and I want to add `file.close` in `__delete__` method. Would you consider this as a good idea? Or does the `__delete__` is used in a different way?

From the docs I am not sure that  am using it right.
http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderdsc/delete.html

Comment: `__delete__` is one of the descriptor methods. Perhaps you want `__del__`?

Comment: @vaultah I added a link to the doc. Once again I am new in Python so I just want to do understand what __delete__ does. What __del__ is?

Comment: `__delete__` is part of the descriptor protocol. Are you writing a descriptor?

Comment: Almost *certainly* you should not be messing with `__del__`, if that is indeed what you mean. You probably want a context manager.

Comment: ...in which case it's `__exit__`, not either `__del__` or `__delete__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb: if you  want to use a destructor for resource management, don't. It's unpredictable and unreliable.

Your options:

- Use a context manager (see [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html)) to deterministically free resources when a scope ends.
- Use a behind-the-scenes list of [weak references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) to resources and an [exit hook](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html); works for most cases of program termination.